# iTextSharp creating corrupt PDF files C#

Tags: c#, itext

This section of my program is in charge of reading the scores from earlier in my program, which is displayed in a couple of text boxes, and creating a .pdf file of this data. Originally, this worked. However, for an unknown reason it has started to create corrupt .pdf files.

Here is the section of my program:

```
private void SaveToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog SavePDFDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        Stream MyStream;
        SavePDFDialog.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        SavePDFDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        SavePDFDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        SavePDFDialog.FileName = ("Report");


            if (SavePDFDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((MyStream = SavePDFDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        Document document = new Document();
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(PDFDirectory, FileMode.Create));
                        document.Open();
                        //Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                        Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("The Top Scoring student is:" + TopStudentBox.Text);
                        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("The Question answer wrong the most is: " + MissedQuestionBox.Text);
                        document.Add(h);
                        document.Add(p1);
                        document.Add(p2);
                        document.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    MyStream.Close();
                }
            }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should provide more details. What do you mean by corrupt files? Are all generated files corrupt or just some? If just some, how their input compares to non-corrupt ones? If you remove parts of pdf elements from the code above, removing which one makes it non-corrupt?

Comment: It would be nice to see one of those corrupt files.

Comment: You create the target file stream for iTextSharp to use like this: `new FileStream(PDFDirectory, FileMode.Create)`. In particular you do not use the `MyStream` you retrieved from `SavePDFDialog.OpenFile()`. As you don't give iTextSharp the stream you appear to want it to write to, it has no chance to create the file properly.

Comment: By corrupt files I mean that I am getting an error message saying that it is when trying to open it with .pdf reader. Also the files created have 0 bytes. It is now all of the time that they are created in this fashion. How would I go about changing this mkl?

Comment: Those files have 0 bytes because you write nothing to them! Look at what you do with `MyStream` - you open it using `SavePDFDialog.OpenFile()` and you close it using `MyStream.Close()` and nothing else. Thus, generating empty files is exactly what you programed.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing @mkl's comment:

I think it's because you write to one stream:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(PDFDirectory, FileMode.Create));
```

and close another:

```
MyStream.Close();
```

I think this should work, but you may need to change a few things:

```
private void SaveToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SaveFileDialog SavePDFDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    Stream MyStream;
    SavePDFDialog.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    SavePDFDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    SavePDFDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    SavePDFDialog.FileName = ("Report");


        if (SavePDFDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((MyStream = SavePDFDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {

                try
                {
                    MyStream = new FileStream(PDFDirectory, FileMode.Create);
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, MyStream);
                    document.Open();
                    //Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                    Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("The Top Scoring student is:" + TopStudentBox.Text);
                    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("The Question answer wrong the most is: " + MissedQuestionBox.Text);
                    document.Add(h);
                    document.Add(p1);
                    document.Add(p2);
                    document.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                MyStream.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it is still creating the 0 byte files.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed the program by removing:

```
MyStream = new FileStream(PDFDirectory, FileMode.Create);
```

I figured this as I am now letting the user choose the save directory, therefore I do not need the PDFDirectory variable and so do not need to tell the program to create a file there, which it was doing. @mlk, you were also right about me not using the `MyStream` Here is the fixed code:

```
private void SaveToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
SaveFileDialog SavePDFDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
Stream MyStream;
SavePDFDialog.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
SavePDFDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
SavePDFDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
SavePDFDialog.FileName = ("Report");


    if (SavePDFDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((MyStream = SavePDFDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
        {

            try
            {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, MyStream);
                document.Open();
                //Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                Paragraph h = new Paragraph("Results from: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("The Top Scoring student is:" + TopStudentBox.Text);
                Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("The Question answer wrong the most is: " + MissedQuestionBox.Text);
                document.Add(h);
                document.Add(p1);
                document.Add(p2);
                document.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            MyStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

}